# Reproducibility when using best_of in GPT-3 settings

Tags: random-seed, gpt-3

I want to do some tests using GPT-3. Instead of setting temperature = 0, I would like to use the best_of function. However, this gives me non-reproducible results since they differ in each iteration of code execution. Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve reproducible/deterministic results and still use best_of? Is there a way to use a random seed in the API for GPT-3?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to understand, why do you want to avoid a temperature of 0?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the temperature to 0 is the best way I'm aware of to achieve something approaching deterministic results.

You could also use fine tuning to push responses in a certain direction.

A final option is to "roll your own" via curation and maybe some type of chaining. If you want a certain response to always be the same, save it to a database and look it up. That might seem like a naïve answer, but solutions like this can be very sophisticated, especially with chain of thought style implementations.